Regex match all words but not in quotes and not list of words
I would like to match all words but not in quotas or escaped quotas and no some words.
My current regex
\b(?![[^"]*"[^"]*"]|AND|OR|NOT\b)\w+/gm

Example phrase:
Visualise AND Visionary OR "Experiences Tester" OR (project AND manager)

My expected result is get following matches.

Visualise, Visionary, project, manager

But right now i receive  Visualise, Visionary, Experiences Teste, project, manager
How to right a correct regex?
Thank you.

I would probably be a lot easier if you didn't try to do this all with one expression, but removed all parts in quotes beforehand.

For the exact task described in the question, you can use
(?:\b(?:AND|OR|NOT)\b|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+

See the regex demo.
Details:

(?:\b(?:AND|OR|NOT)\b|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")(*SKIP)(*F) - match and skip:
\b(?:AND|OR|NOT)\b - a AND, OR, NOT as whole words
"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*" - any string inside double quotes that can possibly contain an escaped double quote
| - or
\w+ - match one or more word chars.

Remember that backslashes must be double escaped inside PHP single/double quoted string literals, see the regex101 code snippet.

Absolutely amazing. Thx.
